# Cannot migrate asp.net mvc database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio

I tried to migrate my database on ASP.NET MVC. I followed the instructions where you have to enable migration using this code:

**Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations**

And when I write **Update Database**

It gives me this:
**Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database**

When I am trying to access the register on the page, it gives me:
** Server Error /in Application**

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps

```
after create your entities in Package Manager Console write "Enable-migrations"
step 2 change  AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false; to true
step 3 write "Update-database"
try and tell me what happen
```

Answer (score 0):

well I had a similar problem where I couldn't enable migrations and that was because I selected an empty MVC template and I didn't activate authentication when I was I creating my project(this only applies to Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 only because with VS 2015 they are automatically enabled)